# How to access gmail api using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail-api

I am trying to access the gmail api for that I am using this [rubygmail](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ruby) guide but everytime I am trying to run the code I am getting different errors I am using this code:

```
 require 'google/apis/gmail_v1'
  require 'googleauth'
  require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

  require 'fileutils'

  OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
  APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Ruby Quickstart'
  CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secret.json'
  CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',
                               "gmail-ruby-quickstart.yaml")
  SCOPE = Google::Apis::GmailV1::AUTH_GMAIL_READONLY

  ##
  # Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
  # files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
  # the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
  #
  # @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
  def authorize
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(CREDENTIALS_PATH))

    client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
    token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(:file => 'gmail-ruby-quickstart.yaml')
    authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(
      client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
    user_id = 'me'
     credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
    if credentials.nil?
      url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(
        base_url: OOB_URI)
      puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " +
           "resulting code after authorization"
      puts url
      code = gets
      credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
        user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
    end
    credentials
  end

  # Initialize the API
  service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
  service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
  service.authorization = authorize

  # Show the user's labels
  user_id = 'me'
  result = service.list_user_labels(user_id)

  puts "Labels:"
  puts "No labels found" if result.labels.empty?
  result.labels.each { |label| puts "- #{label.name}" }
```

When I am running the ruby code I am getting this error:

```
       nilay@nilay:~/gmail$ ruby quickstart.rb
  /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/pstore.rb:414:in `load_data': PStore file seems to be corrupted. (PStore::Error)
    from /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/pstore.rb:328:in `transaction'
    from /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/googleauth-0.5.1/lib/googleauth/stores/file_token_store.rb:49:in `load'
    from /home/nilay/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/googleauth-0.5.1/lib/googleauth/user_authorizer.rb:130:in `get_credentials'
    from quickstart.rb:28:in `authorize'
    from quickstart.rb:45:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this please help me.

Comment: The three lines you posted do not constitute an error. You've posted part of the trace, but cut out the actual error message.

Comment: Now I have added whole error

Comment: You can try to follow the solution in this [thread](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/PStore.html), By default, file integrity is only ensured as long as the operating system doesn't raise any unexpected I/O errors. If an I/O error occurs while **PStore** is writing to its file, then the file will become corrupted. You can prevent this by setting `pstore.ultra_safe = true`. Note: If you're storing valuable data with **PStore**, then you should backup the **PStore** files from time to time. Check this link for more [info](https://github.com/sj26/ruby-1.9.3-p0/blob/master/lib/pstore.rb)

Answer (score 0):

Use this gem
[Gem gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail)

Or [Gem gmail-ruby-api](https://github.com/jhk753/gmail-ruby-api)